# Angular Single Page application and SSRS reports

Tags: angularjs, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, single-page-application

We are creating a SPA with AngularJs and want to integrate our existing SSRS reports in this application. We have SSRS reports already consumed by our WPF application using .Net Report Viewer but, we are not sure how we will be able to that in this web application.

One thought we have is that we can create a ASP.Net application which will have a app folder that contains all the templates of our application and for reports we can have normal aspx page and add  a report view control on that page.

But, we dont want to use ASP.net just for this purpose.

Does anyone has any idea if we can render SSRS reports in simple HTML page and have basic functionality like save, print which are there in report viewer

Thanks for the help

Comment: Tried the same thing. Couldn't get a solution on time. Ended up using asp.net and iframes. Please post the solution here if you find any.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but just in case somebody else will still came upon it, here can be a possible solution for the problem. The solution described here will allow you to display the report as PDF, having the possibility to print or save it.

Integrating SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) with Web-API and AngularJS by Chris Briggs

1. http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/the-first-step-towards-integration
2. http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/How-to-Integrate-SSRS-and-WebAPI
3. http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/AngularJS-SSRS-Pdf-integration

Best,
Razvan