# Angular Single Page application with SSRS reports

Tags: angular, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

There are a few posts out there but no solution to embedding SSRS reports into Angular 13:

[display SSRS reports in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430942/display-ssrs-reports-in-angular)

-- Out of date
[Angular Single Page application and SSRS reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346942/angular-single-page-application-and-ssrs-reports)

I tried using ngx-ssrs-reportviewer but when added to per their instructions it was throwing errors. Perhaps it does not support Angular 13.

Any suggestions other than purchasing a product would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you use an iframe in your Angular component as it's just HTML? Something like this? This is a Power BI link but I've used similar for SSRS <iframe width="100%" height="800" src="http://dgft-pwrbi-p01/reports/powerbi/Mortality%20Tracking/30DayAuditDashboard?rs:embed=true&filterPaneEnabled=false" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

Comment: If you look at the source for "ngx-ssrs-reportviewer" component, it's fairly simple and just renders an iframe. Source here https://github.com/tycomo/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer/blob/master/projects/reportviewer/src/lib/reportviewer.component.ts

Comment: I tried using ngx-ssrs-reportviewer but getting error for: import { ReportViewerModule } from 'ngx-ssrs-reportviewer';  Module 'ngx-ssrs-reportviewer has no exported member ReportViewerModule so I abandoned this solution.  I think I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: I see what you mean. It's such a simple component though. You could either just use an iframe or create your own component with an iframe. You could get some inspiration from https://github.com/tycomo/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer/blob/master/projects/reportviewer/src/lib/reportviewer.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple component that you can write yourself.

The SSRS report can be shown using an iframe...so...

Some inspiration taken from https://github.com/tycomo/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer/blob/master/projects/reportviewer/src/lib/reportviewer.component.ts

Create a component.

report-viewer.component.html:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="800" [src]="source" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false"></iframe>
```

report-viewer.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-viewer',
  templateUrl: './report-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report-viewer.component.css']
})
export class ReportViewerComponent implements OnInit {

  source!: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.source =
      this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://dgft-pwrbi-p01/reports/powerbi/Mortality%20Tracking/30DayAuditDashboard?rs:embed=true&filterPaneEnabled=False');
  }

}
```

And use it in a parent component, e.g.

```html
<app-report-viewer></app-report-viewer>
```

Obviously, you can do something more sophisticated with input parameters and pass in various parameters to make it more reusable.

In the example above, I've hardcoded a Power BI URL, but this could be passed in as a single string from parent component and received by an input parameter in child component.

Personally, I wouldn't use a third-party component for something so simple.